# How can I convert 02-August-2014 to datetime type in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to convert a string of format `02-August-2014` to a `DateTime` in a SQL `Select` statement.

```
select convert(datetime,'02-August-2010')
```

is giving me result as

```
02-August-2010
```

but I want the result in format of `02-08-2010`.

Please help :)

Comment: Not sure, if it goes in plain sql. Which language your backend is written?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: the format of the result doesn't matter, you convert it on output.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Your first sentence says that you want a `DateTime`, but your last real sentence says that you want a certain format, which implies that you actually want a textual representation of the date, *not* a bare `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this !

In `sql-server`

```
declare @a varchar(20)
set @a='02-August-2014'

select cast(@a as date)

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), cast(@a as date), 105) AS [DD-MM-YYYY]
```

`Returns
--02-08-2010`

[SEE HERE FOR MORE FORMATS](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)